# Inserting a RefCursor into a table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a simple function where I run a stored procedure that returns a RefCursor and I try to use that RefCursor to insert data to a temporary table. I get the following error when trying to do so:

`SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values`

I know for a fact that the refcursor returns exactly the same number of values as the temporary table has, correct column names, their order and their type. I ran `print RefCursor` and I can see all of the data. Here's the code:

```
var r refcursor;

EXEC SCHEMA.PACKAGE.SPROC(:r);

insert into SCHEMA.TEMP_TABLE
values
(r);
```

I have to add that the stored procedure has a refcursor defined as a OUT parameter so it returns a correct type. Using `print r;` prints the correct data.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: 
Based on a suggestion I tried to use a fetch to a rowtype variable, but getting Invalid Number exception whenever I attempt to fetch a row:

```
DECLARE
cur SYS_refcursor;
rec SCHEMA.TEMP_TABLE%rowtype;

begin
SCHEMA.PACKAGE.SPROC( cur ); 
LOOP
FETCH cur INTO rec;
EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND; 

INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TEMP_TABLE
  VALUES rec;
END LOOP;
EXCEPTION 
WHEN INVALID_NUMBER THEN
DBMS_output.put_line(rec.move_id); 
end;
```

I added the exception block to see which row is failing and needless to say it is the first one. The stored procedure I run returns a refcursor of a select query from multiple tables. The temporary table defined as the exact copy of the refcursor columns and their types. Not sure what could be causing the exception.

Comment: Your test case is likely going to need to be complete before we'll be able to track down the source of the exception.  Can you post the DDL to create the tables, the DML to insert some data, and the code for the stored procedure?  Obviously, please do your best to simplify things so that you post the smallest test case you can that replicates the problem.

Comment: I think I found where it fails. This happens on the first field that is null. Why would that create an `invalid number` exception though if none of the fields in the table is defined as `NOT NULL`?

Comment: If the problem was a `NULL`/ `NOT NULL` issue, you would get a different error.

Comment: you're right, it's something else. I think for now I will use "with" statement rather than using this temporary table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't insert into a table from a `refcursor`.  You could write a procedure that fetches from the cursor and inserts into the table.  If `schema.package.sproc` returns a ref cursor of `temp_table%rowtype`, you could do something like

```
DECLARE
  cur sys_refcursor;
  rec schema.temp_table%rowtype;
BEGIN
  schema.package.sproc( cur );
  LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO rec;
    EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;

    INSERT INTO schema.temp_table
      VALUES rec;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: That's a great suggestion. I tried this, but whenever it attempts to fetch it, I get an `invalid number` exception. The column names and types are identical, what could be causing that exception?

Comment: @Victor - Can you edit your question to include a test case that reproduces the problem?  It is possible that the query that is used to open the cursor is attempting to convert a string to a number and the string column has some non-numeric data.  It is possible that there is an error in the code.  But it's very hard to debug without seeing the specifics of what is going on.

Comment: If this cursor has millions of records, would there be a performance hit from inserting row-by-row like this, or does Oracle know to optimize it as a bulk insert?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **LOOP + FETCH** to filter the row in **SYS_REFCURSOR**.
Exit the **LOOP** using **"EXIT WHEN ref_%notfound;"**

Example: Have 2 functions.

```
FUNCTION get_data
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
    is
        s varchar2(2000);
        ref_ SYS_REFCURSOR;
    begin
        s := 'select username, password, email from user_info where id  < 100';
        OPEN ref_ FOR s;
        return ref_;
    end;
```

---

```
FUNCTION load_data_in_table
   RETURN varchar2
    is
        s varchar2(2000);
        puser_name varchar2(2000);
        ppassword varchar2(2000);
        pemail varchar2(2000);
        ref_ SYS_REFCURSOR;
    begin
        ref_ := get_data();
        LOOP
            --process_record_statements;
            FETCH ref_ into puser_name, ppassword, pemail;
            s := 'INSERT INTO TEST_USER_EXP VALUES(:user_name, :password, :email)';
            
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE s USING puser_name, ppassword, pemail;
            EXIT WHEN ref_%notfound;
        END LOOP;
        commit;
        return 'OK';
    end;
```